# Mysql Add a New Column to the Table With check Constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add a new age column to the existing customers table. for that new column I want to add a constraint age > 10,

```
 ALTER TABLE customers
 ADD age INT DEFAULT(10),
 CONSTRAINT ageRestriction CHECK(age > 10);
```

I get the following error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT ageRestriction CHECK(age > 10)' at line 3

Comment: CHECK constraints are enforced starting in MySQL 8.0.16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `ADD` before `CONSTRAINT`:

```
ALTER TABLE customers
    ADD age INT DEFAULT(10),
    ADD CONSTRAINT ageRestriction CHECK(age > 10);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8a7fda2ba2a5f9ebb10782eace2589b0) is a db<>fiddle.